# How to make link working in localhost/html

Tags: html, url

I have a pdf document in my computer in c:/xampp/htdocs/test.pdf

I have linked this document (  Click here ) 
in the file nav.html which is also kept in htdocs.

When I open this file by typing in the address bar as localhost/nav.html, then the link does not work. but if I open it by double clicking it in the file nav.html ( in this case the address bar shows file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/nav.html ), the the link works.

How to make the link active in the former case.

Comment: Most likely Apache is either not running or configured to listen on a non-standard port (not port 80)

Comment: Is your apache server running..(wamp or xampp or whatever) ?

Comment: How did you link it ?

Answer (score 0):

- use relatve path `<a href="test.pdf" title="pdf">( click here )</a>`
- Make sure about `test.pdf` file and `nav.html` is located at the same folder `c:/xampp/htdocs/`
- If your page `nav.html` not loads with your localhost/nav.html so you must check apache service status and test port 80
- check your document root in file c:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf

  ```
  DocumentRoot c:/users/farshad/documents/web/
  <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory c:/users/farshad/documents/web/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```

as @Monsieur Tino suggested

Answer (score 0):

Ohai,
try to connect from another computer, and go to your server link (e.g 192.168.1.XX replace XX by the number attributed by your router). Then, test if you can go to your pdf. If it doesn't work, try (I'm guessing your DocumentRoot is C://xammp) :

```
<a href="/htdocs/test.pdf" title="test">Behind this link, there's a pdf</a>
```

Comment: This won't work.web root is located at `/htdocs/` you have to use the relative path as @Farshad suggested or use `http://localhost/test.pdf`

Comment: Sorry, I use Debian on my server, don't know how it works on Windows.